# Linq Multiple Element select

Tags: c#, xml, linq, select

I think I have a relativity good understanding of LINQ however, I am stumbling on selecting multiple elements from  an XML file. Here is a sample of the XML data.

```
<Person>
     <Addresses>
       <Address>1021 E. Ray Rd</Address>
       <Address>453 E. John Rd</Address>
     </Addresses>
     <Picture>www.testpic.com/pic/2834723</Picture>
</Person>
```

So I am trying to parse this data and create my viewmodel person object with the result. Here is a sample of my view model.

```
Public class personmodel
{
   public string picURI {get;set;}
   public List<string> addressLst {get;set;}
}
```

Any insight on how I can fill my addressLst with the multiple address elements? Here is what I was trying to do..

```
var xmlPeople = XElement.Parse(document)

var person = from personfile in xmlPeople.Descendants("Person")
             select new personmodel
             {
               picURI = (string)personfile.Element("Picture"),
               addressLst = personfile.Descendants("Addresses").Select(item =>item.Element("Address").Value.ToList(),
             };
```

This works to grab the first element under the Addresses element and add it to the artists list. How can I extend this to add all the address elements to the list? Any help would be greatly appreciated! Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
addressLst = personfile.Descendants("Addresses").Elements("Address")
                      .Select( a => a.Value).ToList()
```

Comment: Worked exactly as I needed. Thank you!